# Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP returns different value on immediate child_added

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase Push with Server Timestamp, where a `child_added` listener is already listening.

Extremely surprisingly, the value returned to the `child_added` event is ~300ms different from what is in fact stored in the Firebase Database node. Subsequent reads at the same node, provides the 'correct' time as stored at the node. It is only the initial child_added event that is triggered right when the push is occurring, that is returning a wrong time.

Has anyone observed this issue?

```
ref = new Firebase(/some/path);
ref.on('child_added', function (childData) {
   console.log('childData.pushTime = ' + childData.pushTime);
});
ref.push({pushTime: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP});
```

What the console.log prints is off by ~300ms from what is in fact stored at the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour that you are seeing is the expected behaviour.

It occurs because the `child_added` event is fired locally, using a value for `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` that's determined using the local time and the offset of the local clock from the server clock. However, it's not possible to account for the time it will take for the request to arrive at the server - hence the differing timestamps.

If you also listen to the `child_changed` event, it will fire with a snapshot that includes the correct time once the write is complete.

Comment: I had earlier checked the time offset as well, but the time difference did not match. Your explanation of the time it takes for the request to arrive at the server, is what I missed.

So, that rules out an algorithm that I had planned to match timestamps to compare old records with newer ones. Sigh!

Comment: If you also listen to `child_changed`, it will fire with a snapshot that includes the correct time once the write is complete.

Comment: Good answer thanks. So what would be a simple way to avoid handling a wrong ´TimeStamp´? should I just always use ´onChildChanged´ when doing Push like this, since ´onChildAdded´ for a ´TimeStamp´ is not accurate?