# How to handle Firebase ChildEventListener onChildAdded having a TimeStamp

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When using the Firebase `ChildEventListener` I make a push like this:

```
 UserHistoryMap.put(UserHistory.TIME, ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

When `onChildAdded` is called the `TimeStamp` in wrong and the succeeding call to `onChildChanged` will have the right `TimeStamp`. I understand why because of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40443662/firebase-servervalue-timestamp-returns-different-value-on-immediate-child-added) but should I put the same code in `onChildAdded` and `onChildChanged` like this:

```
@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String prevKey) {
    UserHistory addressHistory = snapshot.getValue(UserHistory.class);
        HistoryManager.getInstance().addHistory(
                mFireBaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid(),
                addressHistory.getAddressId(),
                addressHistory.getTime());
        MyLog.i(TAG, "TESTING onChildAdded for " + " time "+ addressHistory.getTime());
}

@Override
public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot snapshot, String prevKey) {
    UserHistory addressHistory = snapshot.getValue(UserHistory.class);
        HistoryManager.getInstance().addHistory(
                mFireBaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid(),
                addressHistory.getAddressId(),
                addressHistory.getTime());
        MyLog.i(TAG, "TESTING onChildChanged for " + " time "+ addressHistory.getTime());
}
```

This works but I feel there must be a better way because for a millisecond according to my code above I actually saving the wrong `TimeStamp`

I could not see any workaround about this in the doc but probably in some Google I/O session I missed, but anyway would love to get some input on this.

This happens of course for the `ValueEventListener` also but that´s obvious how to handle it since it´s only one `onDataChange`

Comment: I don't know what `HistoryManager` is. But it seems likely that you want to **update** the existing `UserHistory` object when you receive `onChildChanged`, instead of adding a new `UserHistory`.

Comment: yes your right and `HistoryManager` is just a singelton... I never update history because it´s final but in the code above I have no chose since `onChildAdded` have the wrong time and the `onChildChanged` the correct time. So is the this the expected way to do it?

Comment: It is expected behavior that `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` first invokes `onChildAdded` with the initial, client-side estimate and later invokes `onChildChanged` with the final value from the server. How your code handles that is up to you, but I'd expect it to **update** the history when it received `onChildChanged()`.

Comment: thanks grate to know